# Simplest task to confirm sudo access with Ansible

Tags: ansible, sudo, ansible-inventory

I am trying to validate I have correctly set up my `inventories/hosts.yml` to remotely provision a BeagleBone Black.

What is a very simple playbook task one can create to confirm one can run a command with `sudo` (thinking something like `sudo apt update`).

---

I have `ansible [core 2.11.12]` with `python version = 3.7.14`, and here is my current `inventories/hosts.yml`:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    testbeagle:
      ansible_host: 10.4.8.120
  vars:
    ansible_user: debian
    ansible_password: temppwd
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    ansible_become_pass: temppwd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't generally use `sudo` directly when working with Ansible. You configure privilege escalation using the `become`, `become_method`, and `become_user` variables. Out of the box, `become` is `false`, `become_method` is `sudo` and `become_user` is `root`. You can test things like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - become: true
      command: id -u
      register: id_output

    - assert:
        that: id_output.stdout == '0'
```

If that playbook runs, it means that Ansible was successfully able to obtain `root` privileges for the task on which we set `become: true`.

Read more about privilege escalation [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html).